# The rtweet search query is returning way less tweets than in previous days

Tags: r, twitter, hashtag, rtweet

I am using the rtweet search query to look for tweets with 2 specific hashtags. I started on 1 Feb 2021 and until 5 Feb 2021 I was getting between 5000 to 10,000 tweets a day. Now I am returning around 800 tweets a day.

I then decided to have expand my search parameters now to include more hashtags, but I am still returning only 2000 tweets.

I thought that including the new hashtags would increase my returns because it would be searching tweets with those hashtags from the last 7 days? (I have the standard Twitter API)

I tried using trending hashtags like #friday but still only get 8-12% of the N=18,000 max return of tweets.

Also, on 5 Feb 2021, there was a new authentication requirement for my Twitter API, since then an internet browser automatically opens saying my account has been authorized and I can return to R.

Here is an example rtweet search query:

`search_tweets(q = "#friday OR #monday -filter:retweets -filter:replies", lang = "en", n=18000, type = "recent", parse = FALSE, retryonratelimit= TRUE)`

THANKS EVERYONE (:

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/enterprise/rules-and-filtering/operators-by-product
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/enterprise/rules-and-filtering/enterprise-operators
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/labs/filtered-stream/guides/search-queries

> Important Note: The sample operator first reduces the scope of the firehose to X%, then the rule/filter is applied tio that sampled subset. If you are using, for example, sample:10, each Tweet has a 10% chance of being in the sample.

I'm not familiar with rtweet. It probably relies on an API endpoint that is affected by that change.
They want you to upgrade your API access. If you figure out an alternative solution, please post it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Upgrading my API wasn't an option ($$$). 

I am now searching the two different hashtags as two separate queries. It isn't a perfect solution, but it is returning me about 8% on each search, so that is more tweets overall at least.